# Site to Post Android App Projects?

Tags: android, upload, directory

I have a folder of 8 completed Android applications that I did for a class. Being two hours away from campus I attempted to email the zipped folder to my professor but received an error saying that google doesn't allow .exe files to be sent. I completely understand that but was curious if there was a site or place where I could upload my folder of Apps for my professor to look at to save me some gas money. Thanks for your time!

I tried GitHub but couldn't figure out how to upload my folder.

Answer (score 0):

Upload the zip to google drive and share the link via email.

Alternatively, you can upload the zip to Mega.co.nz and share the link from there.

If you want to use git, follow this [tutorial](http://tech.pro/tutorial/1840/setting-up-git-and-github-from-the-windows-command-prompt)
It is very straight forward. Comment back with any questions, if you'd like.